# What is the upper limit for 'active' vaccinations

Tags: human-biology, immune-system, vaccination

As far as I know the effect of vaccines is caused mainly by creating Memory Cells specific to a single pathogen.

As there is obviously a lower limit of memory cells needed for immunity ( at least one), and an upper limit for the number of memory cells (they have to fit inside a human)
there is a an upper limit of about a trillion diseases against one can be immune at the same time. But I guess this limit is much lower. Has it ever been studied? And can it be relevant in practice, or could I get a new vaccination every day without loosing previous ones?

Comment: "...could I get a new vaccination every day without loosing previous ones?" Previous what? Previous cells that can react to the antigen? Immunity isn't at a fixed level, like memory in the Cloud, which starts kicking out older information to make room for the new if you exceed what you've paid for. "Has it ever been studied?" Not in the way you present. How would that be useful to know? Also, I don't think it would pass the ethics committee. ("OK, what can we expose this guy to next? Should we try dengue virus?")